# Change in a linear fit in a percentage

Tags: python, regression

My time-series contains monthly data for over 8 years. This is the [file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-7zRxl0D3GJr42JBSWXDyic6_zTXVjY2/view?usp=sharing) and below is the sample of the data.

```
Timestamp   data
2011-02-28  0.899749
2011-03-31  0.900395
2011-04-30  0.901033
2011-05-31  0.901663
2011-06-30  0.902283
2011-07-31  0.902895
2011-08-31  0.903497
2011-09-30  0.904089
2011-10-31  0.904670
2011-11-30  0.905240
2011-12-31  0.905798
2012-01-31  0.906344
2012-02-29  0.906876
2012-03-31  0.907396
2012-04-30  0.907903
2012-05-31  0.908397
2012-06-30  0.908878
2012-07-31  0.909348
2012-08-31  0.909808
2012-09-30  0.910258
```

After plotting a linear fit of the full data, a decline is shown. Please see the graph.

[image]

Now, I want to calculate the **annual** rate of decline in a **percentage**.
These are my attempts, all based on literature:

```
# 1st method
y = ax + b
where a is slope and b is intercept.

annual_relative_change = (12*slope)/intercept

# 2nd method using Logarithmic Transformation in Linear Regression Models
percent_change = np.log(y) - np.log(y.iloc[0])

# 3rd method (pythonic one)
percent_change = df['data'].pct_change()
```

Method 2 and 3 produce exactly the same result which is completely different to the result from method 1. I have no idea which one is correct (if one of them it is). Any help would be great.

Comment: Please can you add a short usable sample of your data instead of a google sheet which needs permission and which is not easily usable. And please, explicit what is `intercept`

Comment: @Clément, the link is fixed and a sample of data added

Comment: Since you have 8 years, the annual rate in percent should be `100 * ((12*slope)/intercept) / 8`, right? Concerning methods 2 and 3, there's no linear fit involved so I'd expect them to differ from the result of method 1.

Comment: @MrFuppes, with that formula, the value got unrealistic. Method 2 uses values from the linear fit.